# how can i put the value of name from registration to dashboard page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

hi i want to put the name from registration page to dashboard page following is my registration page code

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Typography, Paper, Button, FormControl, Input, InputLabel } from '@material-ui/core'
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles'
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { startRegister } from '../actions/auth';

const styles = theme => ({
    main: {
        width: 'auto',
        display: 'block',
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
        marginRight: theme.spacing(3),
        [theme.breakpoints.up(400 + theme.spacing(3) * 2)]: {
            width: 400,
            marginLeft: 'auto',
            marginRight: 'auto',
        },
    },
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: `${theme.spacing(2)}px ${theme.spacing(3)}px ${theme.spacing(3)}px`,
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%',
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    submit: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    },
})



const Register = (props) => {
    const { classes } = props
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const dispatch = useDispatch();


    const onRegister = async () => {
        dispatch(startRegister(email, password));
        props.history.push('/dashboard')
    }

    return (
        <main className={classes.main}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                    Register Account
                </Typography>

                <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault() && false}>

                    <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="name">Name</InputLabel>
                        <Input id="name" name="name" autoComplete="off" autoFocus value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
                    </FormControl>

                    <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email Address</InputLabel>
                        <Input id="email" name="email" autoComplete="off" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                    </FormControl>

                    <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
                        <Input name="password" type="password" id="password" autoComplete="off" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                    </FormControl>

                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        fullWidth
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        onClick={onRegister}
                        className={classes.submit}
                    >
                        Register
                    </Button>

                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        fullWidth
                        variant="contained"
                        color="secondary"
                        component={Link}
                        to="/login"
                        className={classes.submit}>
                        Go back to Login
                    </Button>
                </form>
            </Paper>
        </main>
    )

}

export default withRouter(withStyles(styles)(Register))
```

and i want to put the value of name in displayName that have value null
following is my dashboard page code.

```
 import React from 'react'
import { Typography, Paper, Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles'
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import firebase from '../firebase/firebase';

const styles = theme => ({
    main: {
        width: 'auto',
        display: 'block', // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
        marginRight: theme.spacing(3),
        [theme.breakpoints.up(400 + theme.spacing(3) * 2)]: {
            width: 400,
            marginLeft: 'auto',
            marginRight: 'auto',
        },
    },
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: `${theme.spacing(2)}px ${theme.spacing(3)}px ${theme.spacing(3)}px`,
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%',
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    submit: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    },
})

const Dashboard = props => {

    const { classes } = props
    const onSignout = async (e) => {
        await firebase.auth().signOut()
        props.history.push('/')
    }

    return (
        <main className={classes.main}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
```

> here i want to put the value of name in displayName
> i am doing firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({displayName: name})
> but its not supporting because name from registration is not exported

```
                    {`Welcome User ${firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName}`}
                </Typography>
                <Button
                    type="submit"
                    fullWidth
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    component={Link}
                    to='/'
                    className={classes.submit}
                    onClick={onSignout}
                >
                    Signout
        </Button>
            </Paper>
        </main>
    )
}

export default withRouter(withStyles(styles)(Dashboard))
```

Comment: maintain a context or redux state which you can update from registration page once the user is registered. Use that value in your Dashboard page

Comment: Why can't you submit `name` along with the credentials when registering and upon successful registration (and authentication) update the current user display name? I suppose an alternative would be to send `name` in route state for the transition to the "/dashboard" page to be accessed from `location.state` in `Dashboard`.